# webview won't load with string

Tags: ios, url, search, webview, nsurl

In my webview viewdidload i'm implementing the following code. the problem is the webview won't appear when I include the NSString *encodedString. I have searchString with spaces and sometimes &. Any ideas on what's going on here?

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://google.com?q=%@", searchString];
        NSString * encodedString = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
           NULL,(CFStringRef)urlString,
       NULL,(CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
         kCFStringEncodingUTF8 ));

    NSLog(@"searchString is %@", searchString);
    NSURL *myURL =[NSURL URLWithString:encodedString];
    NSURLRequest *myRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL];
    [searchWebView loadRequest:myRequest];
```

What would it take to generate the first page results of google for this searchString?

Comment: what u get the result in NSLog(@"searchString is %@", searchString);

Comment: searchString is whatever I'm passing from the previous viewcontroller (e.g. "iPhone 4s")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com/search?q=%@",searchString];
   urlString = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


   NSURL *myURL =[NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *myRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL];
    [searchWebView loadRequest:myRequest];
```

Comment: Thanks Kathiravan! Works well.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to encode Your SearchString

```
SearchString=[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", SearchString]  stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet];
```

and then append it to your URL

Comment: I'm getting closer. I added your suggestion and removed nsstring *encode... The google page appears but the text doesn't load into the search bar. Is this an issue with the code or a connection I missed?

Comment: I am guessing more on code, there must be some other key which you would have to add to get the searcString in the proper place